# How can I get data from 3 tables?

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli

I have 3 tables: 'news', 'comments' and 'rub'. I need to get all data from 'news', get 'title' from 'rub' and count the number of comments for every news.

Now I'm not able to get 'title' from 'rub'. The code below works:

```
SELECT n.id,n.header,n.text, COUNT(c.news_id) AS comments 
FROM news n 
LEFT JOIN comments c ON n.id = c.news_id 
GROUP BY n.id 
ORDER by n.id 
LIMIT 30
```

But I need something like that and this code doesn't work (Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object):

```
SELECT n.id,n.header,n.text,r.title COUNT(c.news_id) AS comments 
FROM news n,rub r 
LEFT JOIN comments c ON n.id = c.new_id AND r.news_id=n.id 
GROUP BY n.id ORDER by n.id 
LIMIT 30
```

How to fix it?

Comment: You're missing a comma `,` before the `COUNT` function in your second statement. We can't see your PHP code but I presume you are not checking for database errors prior to fetching results.

Comment: And other typos. What you're doing wrong is what halfter wrote: You do not even ask the database about the concrete error given. You are flying blind. You need to as the database for the error. Also see the many duplicates of this error: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Call+to+a+member+function+fetch_array%28%29+on+a+non-object

Comment: @Narendra, the contraction of "I am" should have an apostrophe in it `;-)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear to me what you are asking, but you need another `JOIN`. And you need to move the join condition for the `rub` table to that `JOIN` keyword, not into the join condition for the `comments` table

```
SELECT n.id,
       n.header,
       n.text,
       r.title, -- comma was missing (as halfer mentioned)
       COUNT(c.news_id) AS comments 
FROM news n
  JOIN rub r ON r.news_id=n.id --- this is missing
  LEFT JOIN comments c ON n.id = c.new_id -- no join condition for rub/news here
GROUP BY n.id 
ORDER by n.id 
LIMIT 30
```

---

Your usage of the `GROUP BY` operator is also wrong. The above query will (rightfully) be rejected by all other DBMS.

Please read the following to understand why your `GROUP BY` is wrong:

- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/
- http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Comment: Yeah, I did it a minute ago!